# quercus and PHP hmac 256 implementation

Tags: php, facebook, hmac, sha

I am trying to use hash_hmac in quercus (php emulation under java), but unfortunately it has not been implemented!

```
Fatal Error: hash_init: 'HmacSHA-256' is an unknown algorithm [hash_hmac]
```

I have 2 options:

1) create a custom php function that will replace the hash_hmac. I found one here, but it's NOT compatible with sha 256:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php#93440

Are you aware of any other custom implementation?

2) let java decode the string and pass it to php. It's doable:

http://php-apps.appspot.com/hmac-sha-256-signature-for-amazon-product-api-requests.html

but It's the first time that I am dealing with php classes and the debugger doesn't accept this php code given in the link:

```
<?php

import phpgae.HmacSHA256;

$c = new HmacSHA256;

echo $c->compute( 'your base string' ,  'your key' );

?>
```

how am I supposed to implement it?

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for hours myself to find a solution to this.

Turns out it was reported as a bug and fixed in version 4.0.29.

See http://bugs.caucho.com/bug_view_advanced_page.php?bug_id=4833#bugnotes

Upgrading to a newer version will fix this.